# parsing url in text message throws (500) Internal Server Error Exceptions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internal-server-error

Whenever an url is getting parsed in text message I am sending to user through asp.net it shows 500 Internal Server error.

```
Dim myMobile As String = "9999999999"
Dim myMsg    As String = "Booking Details " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf 
    & "OEL32017734." & vbCrLf & "30 Pcs. (Auto parts)" & vbCrLf & "Pune-Chennai" & vbCrLf 
    & "Air (Normal)" & vbCrLf & "22/03/2017" & vbCrLf 
    & "OEL Office Pune  To OEL Office Chennai " & vbCrLf 
    & "OEL Office Pune  (Payee)" & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf 
    & "Track your shipment at http://www.orionexpresslogistics.com/track-shipments?bookingID=OEL32017734" & vbCrLf 
    & "Thank you for Booking."

Dim client  As New WebClient()
Dim baseurl As String = ""
Dim Data    As Stream = client.OpenRead( "http://smshorizon.co.in/api/sendsms.php?user=username&apikey=myAPI&mobile=" & myMobile & "&message=" & myMsg & "&senderid=ORILOG&type=uni" )
Dim reader  As New StreamReader(Data)
Dim ResponseID As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Data.Close()
reader.Close()
Response.Write("Sent")
```

Exception

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address) at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(String address) at myadmin_horizon.myadmin_horizon_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\Orion\myadmin\horizon.aspx.vb:line 12

Comment: What is the exact exception message, type and stack-trace?

Comment: I note that you're not correctly encoding the querystring parameter values - that might be causing some problems.

Comment: And is the error 500 being raised by your own code, or by the remote server (at smshorizon.co.in)?

Comment: FYI since you are receiving such little data, you could `client.DownloadString()` instead of using all the stream reading code.

Comment: @Dai Updated exception in post. Also I have notice I am If I parse this url http://www.orionexpresslogistics.com then it works fine. but If I include forward slash after website name http://www.orionexpresslogistics.com/ then it throws Internal server error

Comment: @SUN This is certainly because you are not URL-encoding your `myMsg`.  You should `myMsg = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(myMsg)` before including it in the request URL.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ thanks. It is working now